# Jasper creates empty PDF

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am starting to work with the jasper library. If I try to compile my project, jasper generates an empty PDF. Normally, this main function should generate a pdf file with the text 'hello'. Can anyone help me?

Main.java

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

    JasperReport jasperReport;
    JasperPrint jasperPrint;
    Map<String, Object> parameter = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    parameter.put("aParameter", "hello");

    try {
        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
                .compileReport("C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/helloworld.jrxml");

        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameter);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,
                "C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/helloworld.pdf");

    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

helloworld.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"  ?>
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN" "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">
<jasperReport name="Example1">

 <parameter name="aParameter" class="java.lang.String"/>

 <detail>
  <band height="150">
   <textField >
    <reportElement x="100" y="60" width="100" height="50" />      
    <textElement><font size="36"/></textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{aParameter}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
  </band>
 </detail>

</jasperReport>
```

Comment: You did not pass any datasource or connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The detail band of your report will be repeated for every row in the datasource. However your filling the report with an empty data source, this is why the band is not showing. Try moving your textfield in the `title` band to see it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, Jasper prints the detail-section only if there is report-data ("DataSource") available.

Try using e.g. the title-section.

In addition, Jasper has a "no-data-behavior". The outdated version I was using offered the method "setWhenNoDataType" with 4 predefined values which can be used as argument:

```
JasperReport.WHEN_NO_DATA_TYPE_ALL_SECTIONS_NO_DETAIL
JasperReport.WHEN_NO_DATA_TYPE_NO_PAGES
JasperReport.WHEN_NO_DATA_TYPE_BLANK_PAGE
JasperReport.WHEN_NO_DATA_TYPE_NO_DATA_SECTION
```

Comment: i tried with the title section, i had changed `detail` to `title` , but the pdf file is still empty, can you give me a short example ?

Comment: Ok, this is the solution:

I need to change the tags `<detail>` into `<title>` look at Guillaume post. 

After that I must change this code line in my java class. look ZaoTaoBao post

from:

    jasperPrint =   JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameter); 

into:

    jasperPrint =   JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameter, new JREmptyDataSource());

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you cant print the value at title band or specify empty datasource.